# How to add my HTML5/javascript game to my pre-made website

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

First off, its my first time doing a little bit of game development, and I have no idea of the normal flow of making a game, let alone a browser game.

My game uses the phaser framework of html and javascript. It is a simple game based on the 2D space impact game. I was able to run the game on an empty html site with only head, title, and body tags.

this is the code to plug in my game to the blank html site. The game is in another file which i plug with this line of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when I tried to add it to my pre-made website, it wont show. Am i missing anything? Do I need to put it in an iFrame? but I know phaser builds on a canvas.

Comment: Did you supply game.js in the same directory your "pre-made" site is?

Comment: You are only showing us a typical script element and nothing else. Anything we say about what you've given is only a wild guess. We would need a link or a jsfiddle to help but I'm guessing game.js is not small.

Comment: Yes, it is on the same directory. btw its all running on a local server.

Comment: @Rob yes i thought about that but i dont know which to show :( please tell me which part you want to see. and ill quickly update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it easiest to upload all my game files to a separate, unneeded page (say http://example.org/gamefiles/mygame) and make sure it works there first. Then use an iframe on the page you wish to display it on. I found it helps to have a wrapper on it as well to help with styling, but that's just my personal preference.

```
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
<iframe src="http://example.org/gamefiles/mygame/">
</div>
```

This way, your markup will look a bit cleaner, and you don't need to worry about fixing any broken links once the game works on your separate page.

Comment: I posted my own answer in the gamedev stack. And I used iFrame as this makes sure your html and javascript implementations don't conflict. thanks +1